# One computer, two seats (but not multiseat)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, monitor, multiseat

is it possible to have one computer with two working places, each with its own keyboard+mouse+monitor+sound?

And use it as one user, so just switch between them, working on just one of the places at one time?

So this is different from the "multiseat" setup where it's different sessions and possibly even different users. What I want is just work at one place, then go to another room, press a key and continue working on the second (on the same session). The other place should just go black when it is not used.

It would be great if it's low latency as well (can be used for gaming if I wanted).

Thanks!

Comment: Sure all you need are long cables for the monitor, mouse and keyboard to connect to the computer. Basically what you want is to insert connectors for 2 display, 2 mice, 2 keyboards.

Comment: Depending on distance and type of walls, wireless mouse and keyboard might/maybe work.  This tested on one internal wall and maybe 15, 20 feet.